# How to properly remove bootstrap CDN from `assets.precompile` and isolate controller stylesheets

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, asset-pipeline

I was trying to segregate my CSS to specific controllers by compiling my assets and rendering them in my layouts via `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", params[:controller] %>`

I am using the Bootstrap (4.3.1) CDN and have this in my application.scss file:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

The problem is that when I do `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css )` it must be compiling bootstrap as it gives me this error:

> Sass::SyntaxError in RecipeCategories#index
>
> Undefined variable: "$alert-padding".

**So I'm using this to "solve" it:**

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile = [ Proc.new{ |path| !File.extname(path).in?('.css') }, /bootstrap.css$/ ]
```

**I don't know if this is effective or best practice to prevent bootstrap from being precompiled.**

I also run into the problem where a style defined in one controller's stylesheet is being loaded in the view of another until the page is refreshed. (I put the class on an element in multiple controller views to see if it was really isolated to a specific controller.)

Basically, the style in one controller's CSS file is able to be used in other controllers views until the page is refreshed, then the style is "removed" from the element in the controller view that doesn't have the style in it's CSS file.

Comment: I'm a bit confused so excuse the question. I thought you're only supposed to import if the scss is in the asset pipeline via a gem. You said you're using CDN so doesn't that get grabbed after precompiling?

Comment: I'm using the bootstrap gems too `bootstrap-sass` and `bootstrap-will_paginate`. Am I not supposed to use the gems when I'm using a CDN?

Comment: Can you add your code for how you're implementing the bootstrap CDN?

Comment: And to answer your question, I'm no frontend pro, but typically you either install the gem or get the asset from a CDN, but not both.

Comment: @RudyOnRails Wow. That essentially answered my question, I wasn't aware of that and it lead me to purge my jquery and other bootstrap gems as I'm using a CDN for jquery too. Thank you! It also turns out I don't even need to use my `Proc` to "solve it" now. - I just had to remove the `@import` for bootstrap and the `//= require` for jquery and revert back to my first precompile code.

Comment: I'll add a basic answer of what I said above. Hopefully get some internet points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to mistakenly be precompiling the bootstrap assets via the gem and Rails' asset pipeline **AND** getting bootstrap from a CDN. You only need one or the other, so you can probably remove the gem and just use the CDN.